# Display sharepoint list data to dynamic html table using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint

I am having a scenario where i need to get the list data to be shown in dynamic html table using jQuery to display in site with content editor webpart. Please help me out with this regards thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can use SharePoint Client Context REST API to get the data and display it in a table. Add reference to these three scripts:
1. /_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js
2./_layouts/15/SP.js
3. //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

And use below example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        fnGetData();
    });
    function fnGetData() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Users');
        var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        myquery.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" +
                       "<Where>" +
                        "<IsNotNull>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
    "</IsNotNull>" +
   "</Where>" +
                              "</Query></View>");
        myquery.set_datesInUtc(false);
        myItems = list.getItems(myquery);
        context.load(myItems);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { fnGetDataSuccess(); }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.fnGetDataFailed));
    }
    function fnGetDataSuccess() {
        var txtHTML = "";
        var ListEnumeratorAcc = this.myItems.getEnumerator();
        while (ListEnumeratorAcc.moveNext()) {
            var currentItem = ListEnumeratorAcc.get_current();
            txtHTML = txtHTML + "<tr>";
            txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
            if (currentItem.get_item('Title') != null) {
                txtHTML = txtHTML + currentItem.get_item('Title');
            }
            txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";


            txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
            if (currentItem.get_item('Owner') != null) {
                txtHTML = txtHTML + currentItem.get_item('Owner').get_lookupValue();
            }
            txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";
            txtHTML = txtHTML + "</tr>";
        }
        $("#tblCustomListData").append(txtHTML);

    }
    function fnGetDataFailed(sender, args) {
        alert("Error Message:\n" + "URL: " + sender.get_url() + ". \n\Error Description:" + args.get_message());
    }
</script>
<table id="tblCustomListData" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title
            </th>
            <th>Owner
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) or [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to retrieve the list data. Then it's easy to use jQuery to insert the data into the HTML page.

Comment: Hi Aymkdn i am new to sharepoint can i get some snippet or example on how to use spservices for the same please.Thanks

Comment: I think SharepointPlus is easier to use and has a better documentation and examples. If you want to use SPServices, look at the documentation or search the web because it uses by a large number of people !